# WebRTC ICE connection fails using Angular between safari and firefox even when ice candidates are gathered

Tags: angular, webrtc, shim, zonejs

Calling from Firefox 61.0.1 to Safari 11.1.2 results in ICE connection failed after all of the candidates are gathered in the Angular 5.x app.

The app is using webrtc-adapter to add cross-browser support.

Tested browsers:

- FireFox 61.0.1
- Opera 54
- Safari 11.1.2 + mobile Safari
- Chrome 67
- Edge 42

Platform: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

All other browsers combinations works.

Here are the webrtc logs from firefox:

```
insert 'ice' (registry) succeeded: ice

insert 'ice.pref' (registry) succeeded: ice.pref

insert 'ice.pref.type' (registry) succeeded: ice.pref.type

insert 'ice.pref.type.srv_rflx' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x64

insert 'ice.pref.type.peer_rflx' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x6e

insert 'ice.pref.type.host' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x7e

insert 'ice.pref.type.relayed' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x05

insert 'ice.pref.type.srv_rflx_tcp' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x63

insert 'ice.pref.type.peer_rflx_tcp' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x6d

insert 'ice.pref.type.host_tcp' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x7d

insert 'ice.pref.type.relayed_tcp' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x00

insert 'stun' (registry) succeeded: stun

insert 'stun.client' (registry) succeeded: stun.client

insert 'stun.client.maximum_transmits' (UINT4) succeeded: 7

insert 'ice.trickle_grace_period' (UINT4) succeeded: 5000

insert 'ice.tcp' (registry) succeeded: ice.tcp

insert 'ice.tcp.so_sock_count' (INT4) succeeded: 0

insert 'ice.tcp.listen_backlog' (INT4) succeeded: 10

insert 'ice.tcp.disable' (char) succeeded: \000

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) has no stream matching stream 0-1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1 aLevel=1

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) has no stream matching stream 0-1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1 aLevel=2

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) no streams with non-empty check lists

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) no streams with pre-answer requests

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) no checks to start

Unrecognized attribute: 0x802b

STUN-CLIENT(srflx(IP4:10.0.8.47:57340/UDP|turn.example.com:443)): Received response; processing

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate srflx(IP4:10.0.8.47:57340/UDP|turn.example.com:443)

Write buffer not empty for IP4:0.0.0.0:443/TCP 44 - already armed (@0x160026df4), not connected

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:57340/UDP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:57340/UDP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

Unrecognized attribute: 0x802b

STUN-CLIENT(srflx(IP4:10.0.8.47:53521/UDP|turn.example.com:443)): Received response; processing

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate srflx(IP4:10.0.8.47:53521/UDP|turn.example.com:443)

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:57340/UDP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

TURN(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:57340/UDP|turn.example.com:443)): Succesfully allocated addr IP4:0.0.0.0:63335/UDP lifetime=3600

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate turn-relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:57340/UDP|IP4:0.0.0.0:63335/UDP)

Write buffer not empty for IP4:0.0.0.0:443/TCP 44 - already armed (@0x1600291f4), not connected

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:53521/UDP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:53521/UDP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:53521/UDP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

TURN(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:53521/UDP|turn.example.com:443)): Succesfully allocated addr IP4:0.0.0.0:50605/UDP lifetime=3600

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate turn-relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:53521/UDP|IP4:0.0.0.0:50605/UDP)

Firing write callback (0)

Invoking writable_cb on connected (44)

Writable_cb IP4:0.0.0.0:443/TCP (0 (0x1600291f4) pending)

Firing write callback (0)

Invoking writable_cb on connected (44)

Writable_cb IP4:0.0.0.0:443/TCP (0 (0x160026df4) pending)

UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 1): 0, waiting: no

UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 1): 0, waiting: no

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 2): 0, waiting: no

UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 2): 0, waiting: no

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

TURN(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)): Succesfully allocated addr IP4:0.0.0.0:58399/UDP lifetime=3600

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate turn-relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|IP4:0.0.0.0:58399/UDP)

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

TURN(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)): Succesfully allocated addr IP4:0.0.0.0:56773/UDP lifetime=3600

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate turn-relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|IP4:0.0.0.0:56773/UDP)

ICE(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) Trickle grace period is over; marking every component with only failed pairs as failed.

ICE-PEER(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default)/STREAM(0-1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1 aLevel=0)/COMP(1): All pairs are failed, and grace period has elapsed. Marking component as failed.

ICE-PEER(PC:1531925753097790 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default): all checks completed success=0 fail=1

TURN(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:57340/UDP|turn.example.com:443)): deallocating

TURN(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)): deallocating

TURN(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:53521/UDP|turn.example.com:443)): deallocating

TURN(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)): deallocating

UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 3): 0, waiting: no

UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 3): 0, waiting: no

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

/builds/worker/workspace/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) has no stream matching stream 0-1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1 aLevel=1

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) has no stream matching stream 0-1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1 aLevel=2

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) no streams with non-empty check lists

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) no streams with pre-answer requests

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) no checks to start

Unrecognized attribute: 0x802b

STUN-CLIENT(srflx(IP4:10.0.8.47:55447/UDP|turn.example.com:443)): Received response; processing

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate srflx(IP4:10.0.8.47:55447/UDP|turn.example.com:443)

Write buffer not empty for IP4:0.0.0.0:443/TCP 44 - already armed (@0x14d18e5f4), not connected

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:55447/UDP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:55447/UDP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:55447/UDP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

TURN(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:55447/UDP|turn.example.com:443)): Succesfully allocated addr IP4:0.0.0.0:56397/UDP lifetime=3600

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate turn-relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:55447/UDP|IP4:0.0.0.0:56397/UDP)

Unrecognized attribute: 0x802b

STUN-CLIENT(srflx(IP4:10.0.8.47:57093/UDP|turn.example.com:443)): Received response; processing

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate srflx(IP4:10.0.8.47:57093/UDP|turn.example.com:443)

Write buffer not empty for IP4:0.0.0.0:443/TCP 44 - already armed (@0x14d18fdf4), not connected

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:57093/UDP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:57093/UDP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:57093/UDP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

TURN(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:57093/UDP|turn.example.com:443)): Succesfully allocated addr IP4:0.0.0.0:60501/UDP lifetime=3600

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate turn-relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:57093/UDP|IP4:0.0.0.0:60501/UDP)

Firing write callback (0)

Invoking writable_cb on connected (44)

Writable_cb IP4:0.0.0.0:443/TCP (0 (0x14d18fdf4) pending)

Firing write callback (0)

Invoking writable_cb on connected (44)

Writable_cb IP4:0.0.0.0:443/TCP (0 (0x14d18e5f4) pending)

UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 1): 0, waiting: no

UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 1): 0, waiting: no

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 2): 0, waiting: no

UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 2): 0, waiting: no

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

TURN(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)): Succesfully allocated addr IP4:0.0.0.0:50309/UDP lifetime=3600

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate turn-relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|IP4:0.0.0.0:50309/UDP)

STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

TURN(relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|turn.example.com:443)): Succesfully allocated addr IP4:0.0.0.0:62199/UDP lifetime=3600

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate turn-relay(IP4:10.0.8.47:0/TCP|IP4:0.0.0.0:62199/UDP)

ICE(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1): peer (PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default) Trickle grace period is over; marking every component with only failed pairs as failed.

ICE-PEER(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default)/STREAM(0-1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1 aLevel=0)/COMP(1): All pairs are failed, and grace period has elapsed. Marking component as failed.

ICE-PEER(PC:1531926015943360 (id=25769803783 url=http://localhost:4242/call/1:default): all checks completed success=0 fail=1

+++++++ END ++++++++
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens because both `zone.js` and `adapter-js` are putting their wrappers on top of various RTC methods.

The solution is to add the line below, at the end of the `polyfills.ts` file.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/webapis-rtc-peer-connection';
```

More info:

- https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/883
- https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/920
- https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/948
- https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1019